# Парсер HTML на Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt, парсер

Нужно написать парсер HTML с построением DOM.
Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь хороший Open Source парсер, желательно, написанный на Qt. Хочу просто почитать исходники и написать свой аналог.
Читал исходники htmlcxx, но там бред, написанный за вечерок индусом

Comment: Видимо, очень крутой индус, если пишет за один вечер то, что вам и за месяц не написать.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну вы сами почитайте и поймете о чём я ;)  Да и по большому счёту там писать не много, просто нужен хороший образец. Маловато опыта, чтобы на интуитивном уровне писать

Comment: *Да и по большому счёту там писать не много* ну-ну :-)

Comment: @PinkTux Для первой рабочей версии 4к строк максимум. Неделя работы, если точно знать, что писать. Поэтому и ищу образец, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды, тратя на это кучу времени

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Стандартный QDomDocument не подойдёт, потому что он не сможет обработать HTML, так как это, очевидно, невалидный XML.
Но есть замечательная WIKI-страничка на эту тему: [Handling HTML](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML)

Использовать QtWebKit не получится, так как он с недавних пор (Qt 5.4) заменён на QWebEngine* классы (если не ошибаюсь, там Blink-вебдвижок под капотом). Да и я бы не советовал. Это как ДНК-сиквенсором забивать гвозди.

Answer (score 2):

Что есть для этого в Qt - без проблем находится в родной Qt-шной документации.

А из последних рекомендую посмотреть на проект [MyHTML](https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml). Очень и очень шустр, и на удивление корректен. Правда, там больше C, а не плюсы :-)

P.S. это часть более объёмного проекта [HTML-рендера](https://github.com/lexborisov/Modest), вот здесь про него подробней: https://habrahabr.ru/post/309756/

Comment: Да, я видел это, но, честно говоря, очень не хочется разбираться в чистом Си